# create an interval variable based on a value column

Tags: sql, sql-server, intervals

I work in MS SQL Server. I have a dataset of which a subset looks like below:

```
id;tax
cvw;8525
jhf;9958
dsf;10843
dsd;12001
xyz;12999
dgs;13586
das;14001
fsa;16428
```

Now, I want to replace (or create a new column, either way is fine) some values in the tax-column with its value but where every value above 9999 gets placed in an interval with increments of 1000. So that it would look like this:

```
id;tax;tax_replaced
cvw;8525;8525
jhf;9958;9958
dsf;10843;10000
dsd;12001;12000
xyz;12999;12000
dgs;13586;13000
das;14001;14000
fsa;16428;16000
```

I have tried to find an easy way to code this, but so far failed. I had a thought of creating the interval in a temp table with 2 columns and from there derive the column "tax_replaced" but I can´t find a way to do it. Any suggestions are most welcome!

Best regards,
/T.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to do your value minus the modulo return.

```
DECLARE @val INT = 16428

select @val - (@val%1000)
```

To put it in your code:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN tax >= 10000 THEN tax - (tax%1000) ELSE tax END AS tax_replaced
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works very well and I don´t actually have to create a separate variable which helps with the rest of the task. :)

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want `case` expression here :

```
select *, (case when tax > 9999 
                then floor(tax / 1000) * 1000
                else tax
            end) as tax_replaced
from table t;
```

You can also use `%` operator :

```
select *, (case when tax > 9999 
                then tax - (tax % 10000)
                else tax
           end) as tax_replaced
from table t;
```

Comment: this is not quite right for 12001 this will return 1 instead of 12000

Comment: It looks like OP wants that modulo remainder removed from the tax value in the returned set.

Comment: Hi, its correct! I have found that all 3 answers so far works great. What a great community! Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the `tax` as it is, if it's less than or equal 10000, otherwise replace it by `floor(tax / 1000) * 1000`.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET tax = floor(tax / 1000) * 1000
       WHERE tax > 10000;
```